# Dynamo db Error adding question: { InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Item['options'].S to be a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, amazon-dynamodb

I am using node js and my query to add an item is like this

```
{
 "TableName":"testquestions",
 "Item":{"testid":{"S":"[object Object]"},
 "questionid":{"S":"31478b20-d2a1-11e8-b6a9-756540a0ef19"},
"answer":{"S":"2"},
 "options":{"S":["a. Panel1","b. panel2","c. panel3","d. panel4","e.panel5"]},
  "questiontxt":{"S":"Googler"}
}
```

And my node js query is this.

```
dynamodb.putItem(testq, function(err, testqdata) {
 if(err){
//Somthing
 }else{
 //Somthing
}
```

But this shows an error

```
Error adding question: { 
InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Item['options'].S to be a string
}
```

How can I execute this query "options":{"S":["a. Panel1","b. panel2","c. panel3","d. panel4","e.panel5"]}, This is an object

Comment: Try `"options": {"SS": ["a. Panel1", "b. panel2"]}`. [String Set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html)

Comment: @Saka7 Its worked if you can make it as an answer i can accept the same also JSON.stringify(testid) is retrnign [object object] do you have any sugections regarding this?

Comment: Could you paste the content of `testid`? It looks like `testid` is `[object Object]` before you are trying to "json"-ify it (object was converted to string before `JSON.stringify()` call).

Comment: @Saka7 JSON.stringify(testid) is retrnign [object object]  I am not written the code i am debugging the same :( How can i conform the value is just  [object object]

Comment: Can you `console.log(typeof testid)`?

Comment: @Saka7 I am getting string in log

Comment: So you have string value `"object Object"` in your `testid`. It's not the problem with `JSON.stringify()`, it's the problem with that `testid` object was converted to `string` before. There is not enough information to answer were exactly.
> And I think this is another question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `S`(`String`), but trying to put `Set/List of Strings`, so try `SS` (`String Set`) instead.

```
"options": {"SS": ["a. Panel1", "b. panel2"]}
```

> Read more about [String Set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html)